# connecting GSM 900A module to arduino

Tags: gsm

I am trying to connect my arduino uno to GSM 900A with the help of this tutorial https://elementztechblog.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/interfacing-sim900a-gsm-modem-with-arduino/
but the calling is not being carried out.

The serial output is as following:

```
Calling through GSM Modem
Called 
ÿÿÿÿ
```

and the code is

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup()

{

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Calling through GSM Modem");

  mySerial.begin(9600);
  delay(2000);
  mySerial.println("ATD99abc19965;"); 
  mySerial.println("ATH");
  Serial.println("Called ");
}

void loop() 
{

  if (mySerial.available()) {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're really missing multiple parts here...

Check out this tutorial: http://tronixstuff.com/2014/01/08/tutorial-arduino-and-sim900-gsm-modules/

- First of all, did you power up the SIM900A using its PWRKEY pin?
- And can you send and receive AT commands?

How do you know that you have a valid GSM connection?
Did you try `AT+CREG?` and `AT+CPIN?`

- Do you understand the AT commands you send?

You send `ATD` (with `abc` in the number?) and after that you *immediately* send ATH. Thus you would hang up directly after calling, and probably wouldn't even get to the actual calling part.

---

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial sim900Serial(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
   Serial.println("Calling through GSM Modem");
   sim900Serial.begin(9600);
   delay(2000);
   sim900Serial.println("ATD99abc19965;");
   delay(10000);
   sim900Serial.println("ATH");
   Serial.println("Call ended ");
}

void loop() {
   if (mySerial.available()){
      Serial.write(mySerial.read());
   }
}
```

Also, your code isn't very well formatted. Compare the code above with yours.